# Powershell - Extract only one zip file from many zip files in a folder

Tags: powershell

I have a folder of many zip files and I would like to extract only one of them.

Let's say I only want to unzip test3.zip for example.

c:\docs

- test1.zip
- test2.zip
- test3.zip
- test4.zip

Code:

```
expand-archive -path 'c:\docs\test3.zip' -destinationpath 'test3_Folder'
```

This is creating me a folder, but not unzipping all the files.  Why is this not extracting?   What are some ways to extract one zip of many zip files?  Also, how could you add a password if the zip requires it?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you extract "test3.zip" manually?

Comment: presuming the file is a valid archive, what happens if you use a full destination path?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, if I run it like -destinationpath 'c:\docs\test_3Folder' it does the same, just creates the folder.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JM1 - you are  welcome! [*grin*] [1] the powershell archive cmdlets WILL NOT use passwords for anything. [2] as `Thomas` asked ... does the exact file extract at all? if you copy it to another location and try to extract it to an existing folder ... does it extract?

Comment: The extract manually extracts when I right click on it.  I didn't know if there was a pretty simple way to extract a password protected file among a list of zip files with Powershell.  I can manually do them, just wondered if PS could do it.  Thanks @Lee_Dailey.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: @JM1 - you likely otta add all that detail to your Question so folks can find it easily. if you want to use password protection on an archive, you will need to use another util. i would likely use the command line version of 7zip. ///// i'm out of ideas, so i'll go back to lurking ... good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey, I appreciate the help!  Happy lurking! :)

Answer (score -1):

[`Expand-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/Expand-Archive?view=powershell-7) is the correct command to expand a single zip archive. You are not doing anything wrong. The fact that the result does not contain the expected files may be due to a password protected zip file. Keep in mind that [`Expand-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/Expand-Archive?view=powershell-7) does (currently) not support password protected zip files. It has even problems if filenames are not UTF-8 encoded.

You can use third party tools like the open source tool [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/). It can also be used over the command line and it supports password protection as well as many different compression levels/methods.